# run getelementbyid in function html

Tags: javascript

so in my javascript file i have this

```
document.getElementById('bodyresize').onclick = function()
```

so that when i press a button with this code it starts that function:

```
<button id="bodyresize">Click Me test</button>
```

but 
now i need another button end when i press that a function starts in my html script:

```
 function resizeanshow()
  {
  showhide();

  }
```

in that function first showhide() does its thing
but now the question:

what is the code that i can run bodyresize also in that same function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do:

```
document.getElementById('bodyresize').onclick = function() {
  showhide();
  //do further coding for resizing here
  console.log('resize method');//logs in the console after showhide();
};
```